# Redirect to a visualforce page with a custom parameter

Tags: visualforce, list-view, parameters, page-override

I am overriding the standard Case page with a custom visualforce page.

The custom VF page looks like this:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case"  extensions="CreateNewCaseController">
     // custom code

     <apex:ListViews type="Case" />
</apex:page>
```

I would like to set the default List View to a specific view.  I read about enhancedList but when I set the ID, it removes the picklist to select a different view, which is NOT what I want.  I want exactly what ListView gives me, but with a default view of what I select, no matter what.

**How can I set a parameter in the URL when it is overridden?**

or

**Is there a better method to accomplish what I'm attempting?**

If I manually add &fcf=00B50000007L2QK to the URL, it works perfectly, but I don't know how to have the controller / VF page register it when redirected to it.  And of course, I want the user to still be able to select another View.

Comment: http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/listview-filter-in-apex-with-paging-and-navigation/

Comment: @sfdc Is it possible to do this without having to recreate the entire list view?